# Passing useState using createContext in React.tsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, error-handling

I have defined a context **Transaction** which takes an object and a function.
In **AppProvider** **Transaction.Provider** is returned.
The code is of GlobalState.tsx file:

```
import { createContext, useState } from "react";

export interface IProviderProps {
    children?: any;
}

type Cat = {
    id: number;
    text: string;
    amount: number;
}

type Ca =Cat[]
export const initialState = {
    state: [
        {id:4, text:'hi', amount:234},
        {id:3, text:'hd', amount:-234},
        {id:1, text:'hs', amount:34}
    ],
    setState: (state: Ca) => {}
}
console.log(initialState.state)
export const Transaction = createContext(initialState);

export const AppProvider = (props: IProviderProps) => {
    const [state, setState] = useState(initialState.state);
    console.log(state);
    return <Transaction.Provider value={{state, setState}}>{props.children}</Transaction.Provider>;
  };
```

In App.tsx I have passed the Provider:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { Header } from "./Components/Header";
import { Balance } from './Components/Balance';
import { IncomeExpense } from "./Components/Income_Expense";
import { TransactionHistory } from "./Components/TransactionHistory";
import { AddTransaction } from "./Components/AddTransaction";
import { AppProvider } from './Context/GlobalState'

function App() {

  const [islit, setlit] = useState(true);
  

  return (
    <AppProvider>
      <div className={`${islit? '': 'dark'} body`}>
        <Header islit={islit} setlit={setlit} />
        <div className="container">
          <Balance />
          <IncomeExpense />
          <TransactionHistory />
          <AddTransaction />
        </div>
      </div>
    </AppProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I am trying to change 'state' with 'setState' but it is not working:

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';
import { Transaction} from '../Context/GlobalState';

export const AddTransaction = () => {

  const initialState = useContext(Transaction);
  const [Incexp, setIncExp] = useState('income');
  const [text, settext] = useState('');
  const [amount, setamount] = useState(0);
  const transactions = initialState.state;
  const settransaction = initialState.setState;

  function Addition(e: any) {
    e.preventDefault();
    settext('');
    setamount(0);
    transactions.push({id:Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000000), text:text, amount:Incexp==='income'? +amount: -amount})
    settransaction(transactions);
    console.log(transactions);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Add Transaction</h3>
      <form onSubmit={Addition}>
        <label htmlFor="description">Text</label>
        <input type="text" id="description" placeholder="Enter description..." value={text} onChange={(e) => { settext(e.target.value) }} required />

        <label htmlFor="amount">Amount</label>
        <input type="number" id="amount" placeholder="Enter Amount..." value={amount === 0 ? '' : amount} onChange={(e) => { setamount(parseInt(e.target.value)) }} required />
        <div className="Inc-Exp">
          <div>
            <input type="radio" id="income" name="balance" defaultChecked onClick={()=>{setIncExp('income')}}/>
            <label htmlFor="income" className="inc-col">Income</label>
          </div>
          <div>
            <input type="radio" id="expense" name="balance" onClick={()=>{setIncExp('expense')}}/>
            <label htmlFor="expense" className="exp-col">Expense</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <input className="btn" type="submit" value="Addtransaction" />
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Another child component:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { Transaction } from '../Context/GlobalState';

export const Balance = () => {

    const initialState = useContext(Transaction);
    const transactions = initialState.state;
    var total=0;
    transactions.map((transaction) => total+=transaction.amount)

    return (
        <div>
            <h4>Your Balance</h4>
            <h1 className={`${total > 0 ? 'plus' : ''} ${total < 0 ? 'minus' : ''}`}>${total}</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Every time I click on a button Add Transaction. I want it to update state. but it is not updating.

Comment: From what I understood you declared `setState` as a function that gets input values, but when you call it you are not seem to use it as a function. Expected something like: `initialState.setState(value_here)`. Please explain what are you trying to do, and what went wrong, and what error do you get

Comment: Every time I click on a button Add Transaction. I want it to update state. but it is not updating.

Comment: what error do you get? error is thrown?

Comment: no error is given I mistakenly typed it.

Answer (score 0):

Please change `setState` to a callback variant `setState((previousState) => {...})` as:

```
function Addition(e: any) {
    e.preventDefault();
    settext('');
    setamount(0);
    transactions.push({id:Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000000), text:text, amount:Incexp==='income'? +amount: -amount})
    settransaction(transactions);
    console.log(transactions);
  }
```

to

```
function Addition(e: any) {
    e.preventDefault();
    settext('');
    setamount(0);
    settransaction((prevState) => {
return prevState.push({id:Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000000), text:text, amount:Incexp==='income'? +amount: -amount});
    });
  }
```

The `console.log` may not show updated value, as re-render would be required to get updated `context` value.

But after `context` update a re-render would going to be trigger by `react`, and thus the `component` responsible to show updated `state` will eventually display the updated state.

Comment: I tried this but it is giving me an error.      Argument of type '(prevState: any) => any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Ca'.
  Type '(prevState: any) => any' is missing the following properties from type 'Cat[]': pop, push, concat, join, and 27 more.ts(2345)
Parameter 'prevState' implicitly has an 'any' type.

if I change prevState: any and in file GlobalState.tsx (the first file I mentioned) if i set setState: (state: any) => {}
the console.log gives me a number instead of array of objects

Answer (score 0):

The state is not update because you are not changing the reference of the object transactions, do it like below

```
  function Addition(e: any) {
    e.preventDefault();
    settext('');
    setamount(0);
    settransaction([...transactions,{id:Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000000), text:text, amount:Incexp==='income'? +amount: -amount} ]);
    console.log(transactions);
  }
```

In this case the object you pass to settransaction will have a new reference the react will update the state